# ハンバーガーメニューを追加したいけどcssがうまく効かない

Tags: css

codepenというサイトにあったメニューバーを自分のサイトに追加したいのですが、貼り付けだけではこのようになり
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

うまく行きませんでした。ul部分のcssが効いていないような気がします。
https://codepen.io/victorfreire/pen/QywRNM

htmlはこのようになっていてbootstrapを読み込んでいます。
詳しい方ご回答よろしくお願いします。

```css
@keyframes checked-anim {
  50% {
    width: 3000px;
    height: 3000px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes not-checked-anim {
  0% {
    width: 3000px;
    height: 3000px;
  }
}

li,
a {
  /* ここがうまく適用されていないです。*/
  margin: 75px 0 -55px 0;
  color: #03A9F4;
  line-height: 1.8;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: none;
  list-style: none;
  outline: 0;
  display: none;
}

li {
  width: 230px;
  text-indent: 56px;
}

a:focus {
  display: block;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #eee;
  transition: all .5s;
}

#trigger,
#burger,
#burger:before,
#burger:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  background: #03A9F4;
  width: 30px;
  height: 5px;
  transition: .2s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}

#trigger {
  height: 25px;
  background: none;
}

#burger:before {
  content: " ";
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
}

#burger:after {
  content: " ";
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
}

#menu-toggle:checked+#trigger+#burger {
  top: 35px;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transition: transform .2s ease;
}

#menu-toggle:checked+#trigger+#burger:before {
  width: 20px;
  top: -2px;
  left: 18px;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(-5px);
  transition: transform .2s ease;
}

#menu-toggle:checked+#trigger+#burger:after {
  width: 20px;
  top: 2px;
  left: 18px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(-5px);
  transition: transform .2s ease;
}

#menu {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  animation: not-checked-anim .2s both;
  transition: .2s;
}

#menu-toggle:checked+#trigger+#burger+#menu {
  animation: checked-anim 1s ease both;
}

#menu-toggle:checked+#trigger~#menu>li,
a {
  display: block;
}

[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked),
[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="checkbox" id="menu-toggle" />
  <label id="trigger" for="menu-toggle"></label>
  <label id="burger" for="menu-toggle"></label>
  <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Python検索エンジン</h1>

      <form method="post" action="{{url_for('index')}}">
        <!-- ここでもう一度サーバーにアクセスしている -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="keyword" placeholder="キーワードを入力して下さい.">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-2">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-block btn-primary" value="検索">
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>

      <br>


    </div>
    <!-- container -->
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `font: 14pt "Roboto", sans-serif;`という行が抜けていますけどもこれは意図したものですか？さらにCSSのコメントアウトは`/*~*/`と書くようにお願いします。

Comment: はいfontの設定ですので意図したものです。コメントアウトのご指摘ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

codepenをみたところ問題ないようでしたが、質問投稿以降に解決したのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

ページを再読み込みしたらうまく動きました (本人による質問文への追記より)。